# Convert JSON -> Ruby Hash to Array of Hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Mandrill sends back JSON data to my web-hook and when converted to Ruby data structures it looks like the below:

```
{ "image.jpg" => { "name => "image.jpg", "type" => "image/jpeg", "content" => "", "base64" => true } }
```

They send this, when what I need is an Array of Hashes, ex:

```
[{ "name => "image.jpg", "type" => "image/jpeg", "content" => "", "base64" => true }]
```

How can the first set of data be converted to an array of hashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the returned data to foo:

```
foo = { "image.jpg" => { "name" => "image.jpg", "type" => "image/jpeg", "content" => "", "base64" => true } }
```

Then do:

```
Array.wrap(foo["image.jpg"])
```

Also, you're missing a closing quote symbol after the first "name" key in your hash

Edit: You can just set it to foo then run:

```
foo.values
```

Comment: It needs to be dynamic, can't statically use "image.jpg" because it will differ.